# How do I listen for changes in global window variables with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, global-variables

Say I have some links on my site which redirect to another domain, and I need to make sure that any tracking parameters also get passed over to that second domain.

Most of these tracking parameters are easily appended to the links' href attributes in the following way:

```
const tracking1 = useSelector(state => state.global.tracking1)
const redirectParams = useSelector(state => state.global.redirectParams)

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(updateParams({ tracking1 }))
}, [tracking1])

...
<a href={process.env.OTHER_DOMAIN + redirectParams}>
```

Thus, if param1 is changed anywhere in the app, the URL here (and everywhere else) will be updated accordingly. This works fine.

But, I have an external script which saves some parameters to an object in window, let's call it `window._external`. I don't have control over when this happens. How can I listen for changes in `window._external` and dispatch those changes? Simply adding `window._external` to the variables array in useEffect's second argument does not seem to do it, and I believe that's because it's only able to "listen" to state or store changes.

Comment: You could likely use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to "listen" for changes, or just consume the global values directly when rendering the link.

Comment: If you don't control the code that changes `window._external`, swapping it out with a "wiretapped" proxy (as mentioned by the above comment) or polling for changes are the only ways I can think of. A workaround could be to attach a click handler to the "other domain" link, in React, and then at that moment read from `window._external` and use the up-to-date params before redirecting. This would guarantee that the link is correct when it's clicked, but not all the time.

Answer (score -1):

You don't, `useEffect` is not meant to do that.